# Fixed Menu breaks under IE9

Tags: css, menu, internet-explorer-9, fixed

So, I'm having an issue with a website I'm designing for my Aunt. Please note, I haven't worked on a website from scratch in a while (I mostly work with Wordpress themes these days). So I've been relearning CSS and HTML5 over the last couple of days. That said, I've been running into problems and reverting back to TABLES for the layout (I know, I know, god help me).

While, I will eventually move this layout to pure CSS, there was a deadline with her latest book, so I needed to rush the design (hence, the tables). I also used Boilerplate as a starting point.

For now, everything works, with the exception of one REALLY annoying quirk in IE9.

The fixed menu I made breaks in IE9. Rather than spanning the whole width of the page - as it does everywhere else - it now begins at the edge of the page's content.

The page: [www.evastachniak.com](http://www.evastachniak.com)

Oddly enough, this problem doesn't occur in IE8 or IE7. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the code for the fixed menu:

```
<div id="container" > OLD SCHOOL TABLED MENU </div>
```

And here is the CSS attributed to it:

```
#container {width:100%;
height:40px;
background:#8a282c;
position:fixed;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 40px #000;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 40px #000;
box-shadow: 0px 5px 40px #000;
z-index:100;}
```

I've spent all day searching google for an answer, to little luck. I'm afraid this problem is currently beyond my realm of understanding. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I like Kolink's answer below.  You need to specify the position.  Also, you should [validate your HTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.evastachniak.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)... it's just going to be a big cross-browser headache otherwise.  Visually, I like it.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it will be of much help. Thanks for the kind words about the visuals, I've never had a problem with design, just the coding part. I should probably look into a part time coder for projects like this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to add `left: 0px` - you're not specifying where you want the element so by default it's where it would be in the flow.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have taken care of it on my end. I appreciate the help!